# CSS Style Individual <div=id

Tags: css, html

I have a ccs sheet with the usual tags
    a. {}
    a.hover {}

I also have a div=id "footer" that I want to change the font style but the global a. and a.hover are overriding it even when I add a

```
#footer{
    color: #333333
}
```

Can I override using this or do I need to try? `a.#footer` or `a.hover:#footer`

Basically the #footer as is wont work because of the a. mentioned above even though the other elements are working in the `#footer` div such as margin...just the font color and hover??

Can someone tell me how to style this and not let the global a. interfere with it?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you add your markup ?

Comment: I can but got it working now thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
#footer a,
#footer a:hover{
 color:#333;
}
```

Comment: Hi that works thanks, can I override the #footer a:link to with, #footer a:link{
  color:#555;
}

doesnt seem to do anything

Answer (score 3):

It's all about the hierarchy of code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Sample link</a>
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="#">Footer link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    color: #ebebeb;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#footer a {
    color: #3e3e3e;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #609;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is dot after `a` ?
the correct form is `a {}` , `a:hover {}` , `a#footer` and `a:hover #footer`

Comment: dont worry
no prob ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are nesting `a` inside `div` element you need to use

```
#footer a {
    color: #333333;
}
```

If you only use `#footer {}` it will apply the styles to `div` and `a` won't inherit the color, so you can also write

```
#footer {
   color: #f00;
}

#footer a {
   color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Styling the `<a>` elements directly is more specific then just applying some CSS to the `<div id="footer">` element and all of its children. You can target any links within your footer by using

```
#footer a {
    color: #333;
}
```

Due to the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) this rule itself is more specific than the one you're using for all the other `<a>` elements outside of the footer.